# facebook connect in symfony2 how do it?

Tags: php, symfony

I would like on my website to allow logging in via facebook connect.
But I do not want to use FOSUserBundle

I already have an authentication database, which I did like in this link http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html

Creating a login through facebook connect I can only do what is in that link?
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html

do I have to do it this way?
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

How do I implements this method: function loadUserByUsername ($ username)?

Comment: Have you looked at [FOSFacebookBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle)? It doesn't require FOSUserBundle.

Answer (score 0):

As @meze mentioned you can either use the FOSFacebookBundle or if you want to implement it yourself you can use KnpOAuthBundle